# how do I add a foreign key pointing to the same table using phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, self-join, phpmyadmin

I have an existing InnoDB table which already has foreign keys pointing to different tables.

But when I try to create a foreign key pointing to the Primary index, I get an error (check data type).

The table is User with User_Id as the Primary.

I want a foreign key Manager_ID which is a FK to User_Id.

Both of INT
Both of Length 10
Unsigned...

But I still get a data check error...?

Comment: Are you talking about giving a table a foreign key *to itself*?

Comment: That is what it seems. But maybe we are mistaken since he also talks about an InnoDB table. I think we may need more information about the database schema. My answer may or may not be what he is looking for.

Comment: Nothing wrong with having a foreign key to the primary key of the same table is there, e.g. usertable has FK link between loan officer and loan supervisor.

Comment: That "length of 10" has nothing to do with the size of the integer.  This is a common misconception about MySQL.  INT(10) only means it pads to 10 digits if you *also* define the column as ZEROFILL.

Comment: can you post a brief structure of your tables?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure that Manager_ID is **not** set to `NOT NULL`.

You have to allow nulls on that field, as the top-most person in the company will have no manager.

<strike>I found [a post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?135,187196,189519#msg-189519) over on the MySQL boards that might help.</strike>